# How to Get data sequentially from Core Data?

Tags: core-data

Every time i am fetching data from core data the sequence of data is different. I just want to fetch data in a sequence order, Means the data is stored in to core data, I want the same sequence at the time of fetching data.

I don't want to use ascending order and IDs.

Please help me. if there is any other way to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Core Data doesn't keep track of the order in which you added the data. The information's just not there. If you want to retain that order, your entity description needs to include some value you can use to sort the fetch results. That could be a unique integer ID, or a timestamp, or something else you think of. You say you don't want that, but with Core Data it's necessary.